# remove value from array if it matches string - php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like the below:

```
staff : staff,company
managers : managers,staff,company
executives : executives,staff,company
customers : customers,company
loyalty members : loyalty members,customers,company
non loyalty : non loyalty,customers,company
```

The array is made with the following command:

```
array_push($group_array, "$group : $area");
```

This array is created from the output of a command and i would like to remove the values staff and customers because for my purposes they are basically parents so i dont want them in my array.

I have been trying to find a way to essentially do this (not my actual php cod)e:

```
if array_value contains ",group," then remove it
```

To try and do this i have been trying to use strpos but i cant figure out how to compare the separate areas of my array values.
This has only removed all items from my array:

```
if (strpos($area, ",$group,") !== false) {
    $group_array = array_diff($group_array, group_array(",$group,"));
 }
```

Additionally my array will not always match exactly the above but it will always follow the same layout e.g. group : group,parent,parent

I am using php in a html page, if i run this at the bottom of my page:

```
foreach($group_array as $items ){
    echo "$items <br>";
}
```

My output is blank. I guess because my if is matching everything?

Expected (hoped for ) array would look like this but it is not as simple as remove item 0 and 3 because the array may change:

```
managers : managers,staff,company
executives : executives,staff,company

loyalty members : loyalty members,customers,company
non loyalty : non loyalty,customers,company
```

I know i have not worded this well and im expecting a torrent of abuse and downvotes but im trying my best to explain my task and goal.

Comment: Please share actual `print_r` of your input and expected output php array.

Comment: Instead of removing them from the final array would it be possible to not add them in the first place? A bit more code example would help!

Comment: the if is clearing my array of any values. im hoping for it to be my array without the string values starting with Staff and Customers

Comment: @ThomasGregory higher up in my code i am running a command that builds a much bigger array i am am picking out of that my $group and $area. I can remove it before this part of my code but the problem is the same. How to remove values that contain the string ",$group,"

Comment: So, you want save items 1,2,4,5 ?

Comment: @splash58 I do but its not necessarily always going to be items 1,2,4,5 unfortunately.

Comment: @a.smith it seems I may have misinterpreted your question. What exactly is your expected output from the sample data you have given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this. Extract all the group names mentioned between commas using [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and using `preg_match_all` to find them:

```
$groups = array_reduce($group_array, function ($c, $v) { 
    preg_match_all('/,(\w+),/', $v, $matches);
    return array_merge($c, $matches[1]);
}, array());
```

Since there may be duplicates we pass this array through [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and then create a regex to match each of the values:

```
$regex = '/^(' . implode('|', array_unique($groups)) . ')\s*:/';
```

Then use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to process each value in `$group_array`, removing those whose value to the left of the `:` is in the `$groups` array:

```
$group_array = array_filter($group_array, function ($v) use ($groups) {
    return !preg_match($regex, $v);
});
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => managers : managers,staff,company
    [2] => executives : executives,staff,company
    [4] => loyalty members : loyalty members,customers,company
    [5] => non loyalty : non loyalty,customers,company
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YqNAi)

Comment: I get the impression you will know how to achieve what im aiming for but this is not quite it. Rather then remove "staff" from the managers and executive strings i want to remove the item staff and like wise the item customers.

Comment: @a.smith yeah, I've read all the comments since I posted the answer and I realised I misinterpreted your question. I'll edit...

Comment: @a.smith I think this new version will give you the results you actually want...

Comment: Thanks @nick i can see this working in your demo but in my code its still giving me the full array when i loop through it. I have even added the foreach loop that i have in my code to the demo. I am doing and array shift on it before your code because of a different issue with the array and that is fine, if i remove it the first item is put back into the array as expected. So the array is all there when im echoing it out to the page. I dont think your going to be able to help without seeing it all but its fairly long and pretty messy because it used ldap to create the array.

Comment: Ive updated your demo to give a better reflection of what im doing but it works in there just not in my live code

Comment: Do you perhaps have group names with spaces in them? If so this should work: https://3v4l.org/r1ZiH

Comment: Still the same. The only thing i can really see different is i define the array $group_array as an empty array first so i can use array_push when i get the values i need to put into the array. I added my entire code to the demo site and after getting rid of the ldap specific bits it works as expected so no idea whats wrong with my actual code. Thanks for all your help anyway.